# Input function into linked list

Tags: c

Having issues with this function when I try to do add(myList)

```
void add(struct employeeData *List)
{

    struct employeeData *Temp = NULL;
    struct employeeData *Head = NULL;

    Head = List;
    Temp = List;

    while (List != NULL)
    {
        List = List->next;

        if (List != NULL)
        {
            Temp = List;
        }

        else
        {
            break;
        }

    }

    List = (struct employeeData*)malloc(sizeof(struct employeeData));

    printf("Please enter the information of the employee");
    scanf(" %d %s %d %d %d ", &List->EMP_ID, List->name, &List->dept, &List->rank, &List->salary);

    Temp->next = List;
    List = Head;

}
```

After I put in my information when it asks for it the program just sits there until I close it or it crashes.

Comment: Please show the declaration of `employeeData`.

Comment: There is a significant amount of code that needs to be added to enable anyone to replicate this issue.

Comment: The rest of the `add()` function, at least, might be useful. Or is there supposed to be a closing brace just after `List = Head;`?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a null pointer to your `add()` function then the behavior of
this line is undefined, because `Temp` is set to a null pointer:

```
Temp->next = List;
```